# How does spock determine which iteratable is greater than the other?

Tags: groovy, spock

I'm reading this doc in spock: http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1/data_driven_testing.html and came across Data Variable Assignment part which has this snippet of code:

```
a = 3
b = Math.random() * 100
c = a > b ? a : b
```

but what if I tried using an iterable

```
a << [6, 2, 0]
b << [4, 10, 10]
c = a > b ? a : b
```

Comment: In this case it will take and compare elements one by one: 6 with 4, 2 with 10, 0 with 10 - is that what you're asking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't.

Spock does heavy rewriting of your test specifications (by registering AST transformations with the groovy compiler).

For the `where:` clause it creates code to iterate over to provided lists for `a` and `b` (and assigning each value in turn to these local variables) and it runs the code for `c = a > b ? a : b` on each iteration.

The code transformation for the `where:` clause is located in the class `org.spockframework.compiler.WhereBlockRewriter` (https://github.com/spockframework/spock/blob/master/spock-core/src/main/java/org/spockframework/compiler/WhereBlockRewriter.java)